# Rails remote form, replace after create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have a typical "create" form action, that's set to be a remote call.

What I want to do is after the form is submitted, replace the form with the "edit" view with an additional form field, so that once they submit that second form, it updates instead of creating a new record.

So basically, the form would change from "create" to "edit"...but all via ajax calls.

I'm running Rails 3.2.

Comment: You could make your action respond to js and add an create.js.erb and add there something like `$('#new_product_form').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("edit_product_form"))%>');`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make an AJAX POST to `/resources`

## Controller

```
def create
  ...
  # you set @resource to be used in edit form
  @resource = Resource.create params[:resource]

  respond_to do |format|
    # tell controller to respond to requests with JS format
    format.js
  end
  ...
end
```

Actually if you want just that behaviour you can remove anything in your controller.

```
def create
  ...
  # you set @resource to be used in edit form
  @resource = Resource.create params[:resource]
  ...
end
```

Be sure to make the POST with JS format:

```
<%= form_for @resource, format: :js %>
```

## View

file `create.js.erb` is served by controller, and run by browser.

```
$(selector).html("<%= escape_javascript( render 'edit') %>")
```

You have to define `selector` according what you have in page with form for new items.

file `_edit.html.erb` is rendered inline in previous file

```
<%= form_for @resource, remote: true do %>
  ...
```